# Entrada una cadena y decida si esta corresponde a una contraseña segura

Tags: java, string, seguridad, caracteres, contraseña

La contraseña debe ser `mayor o igual a 10 caracteres` que contengan `letras`, `números` y `SIMBOLOS`, necesito ayuda por que no e podido hacer que el programa detecte los símbolos para que sea segura.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class clavejsjs {
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner clave = new Scanner(System.in);                        
     String Contraseña;
     System.out.println("Ingrese una contraseña:");
     Contraseña = clave.next();                                      
     
     if (si_sirve(Contraseña))                                       
         System.out.println("La contraseña ingresada es segura.");
     else 
         System.out.println("La contraseña ingresada no es segura."); 
         
    }
    
    static boolean si_sirve(String Contraseña) {
        if (Contraseña.length() >= 10) {                              
 
            boolean numero = false;                                  
            boolean letra = false; 
            char Pas;
        for(int i=0; i<Contraseña.length(); i++) {                   
                Pas = Contraseña.charAt(i);                            
                
                if (Character.isDigit(Pas))                           
                    numero = true;
                
                if(Character.isLetter(Pas))                          
                    letra = true;
            }
            
            if (numero && letra)                                 
                return true;
            else  
                return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: un símbolo sera algo que no es un dígito ni una letra entonces podes usar la siguiente condicional `if(!Character.isLetter(Pas)&&!Character.isDigit(Pas)){simbolo=true;}`  [ejemplo](https://www.codiva.io/p/5dbab5f0-ae69-4080-8772-afd9c43dd868)

Comment: Usa una expresión regular, con ello simplificarás tu código y le puedes agregar la estructura que desees a la cadena de texto que deseas validar. Puedes probar en  [1]: https://regex101.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que establecer un criterio para determinar cuándo un carácter es un símbolo o no.

Como comentaron, puedes decir que si no es letra ni dígito, es un carácter. Sino no.

Agregando eso y reescribiendo el código para mejorar su legibilidad, obtienes lo siguiente:

```
static boolean si_sirve(String contraseña) {
    // Es más claro evaluar la condición opuesta
    // y salir de la función que tener muchas
    // estructuras anidadas.
    if (contraseña.length() < 10)
         return false;
            
    // Usar variables con nombres significativos permite
    // que el código se explique solo y con menos o
    // incluso nigún comentario.
    boolean tieneDigito = false;                                  
    boolean tieneLetra = false;
    boolean tieneSimbolo = false;

    char c;

    for(int i = 0; i < contraseña.length(); i++) {                   
        c = contraseña.charAt(i);

        // Puedes conectar los ifs ya que las condiciones
        // son excluyentes. Un carácter no puede ser
        // una letra no puede ser un dígito ni un símbolo 
        // al mismo tiempo.
        if (Character.isDigit(c))                           
            tieneDigito = true;
        else if (Character.isLetter(c))                          
            tieneLetra = true;
        else
            tieneSimbolo = true;
    }

    // Quizá te veas tentado a escribir este código:
    //
    //   if (tieneDigito && tieneLetra && tieneSimbolo)
    //       return true;
    //   else
    //       return false;
    //
    // Pero la condición ya es una expresión que produce
    // un booleano así que puedes devolverla directamente.
    return tieneDigito && tieneLetra && tieneSimbolo;
}
```